# How to plot a graph with a condition?

Tags: education

I have been trying to get codes to plot a given graph together with its condition. The equation is

```
s(t) = 976((0.835)^t - 1)) + 176t for 0 ≤ t ≤ 20
```

I have surfed the internet and done some research but some answers still wouldn't satisfy me.

Comment: Have you seen [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html).

Comment: @Edmund Yes but how do I add the condition to it?

Comment: Read the documentation.  There are instructions and interactive examples.

Comment: `Plot[expression , condition/interval]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done with a very straight-forward application of `Plot`.

```
Plot[976 (0.835^t - 1) + 176 t, {t, 0, 20}]
```

[image: plot]

Note: you don't really have a plot with a condition. What you have is a plot with a specified domain. The 2nd argument of `Plot` is the domain specification.